# Wordpress display div if selected a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP blog, and for 1 blog category, I want to add additional `div`. Can someone please to create if/else statement? Lets check it by `category_name = test it` or `slug = testit`

Here is pseudo code:

```
if category_name = test it { 
    show div here
}
```

I know that I can create a custom type post, but I don't want to mess with it, because part which should be added is too small.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to show a certain div only if the post belongs to a certain category, try the code bellow

```
<?php
if(in_category('category_slug')){
?>
your div and content here..
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: additionally you can refer this codex link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

Comment: Its pleasure to help you